# What does circled number means in right down corner of the system tray in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

I have a number in system tray which is `7` in this picture:

[image]

What is it? If it is a number of some messages, then how to see them?

If I hover mouse it says

[image]

but I found no way to see these notifications.

Comment: It's just Windows, lower your expectations. If you reboot, the number will be correct.

Comment: What is "correct" number?

Comment: just click it you will see application notification in it. The 7 means you have 7 notification from your applications such as Mail, outlook,  games and others.

Comment: How to see them?

Answer (score -1):

If there's nothing in the notification window that slides out when you click the icon, try clicking on the various buttons at the bottom of it, using the **Expand** link if necessary to see more buttons. If that doesn't work, then maybe Aganju's on to something.